# Which flag for off-topic, but specified questions?

Tags: support, flags

Related to this specific question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242055/i-can-not-buy-google-maps-image-apis-for-business

Which clearly does not belong on Stack Overflow – I mean, he's asking where to buy a tool. But I wasn't sure how to flag it – it's off-topic, but none of the flag options I get when I choose 'off-topic' really apply – it doesn't belong on Super User or Server Fault either, it's not really opinion based, etc.

It's not really unclear what he's asking either – it just isn't on topic for this site. And although I am not 100% sure, it doesn't really look like spam either.

I could just use 'other' and flag for a mod's attention, but just wondering if there is something in the existing options more appropriate.

Comment: You could use a custom close reason: _This question appears to be off-topic because it is about buying a commercial product.  Please contact the vendor instead._

Answer (score -3):

I feel you should use other flag and let moderate decided if its off topic or not in this case. As you are not able to use off topic flag.